# Should I allow project partner to have remote desktop access to my computer?

Tags: remote-desktop

A potential project partner (I never met him; a friend worked with him) needs to have Anydesk access. He needs IP from my region to access some servers, so VPN would not work for him.

What are the security risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use your desktop as a VPN. If this works to allow access, then great. But you are exposing the desktop to this person.

You ask about risks. A risk assessment is straightforward:

- what are the things that you don't want to happen?
- what is the likelihood of those things happening?
- what would the impact be?
- what can you do to decrease the likelihood or impact to a more acceptable level?

The bad things all seem to be around someone having access to your computer. Since you are granting access, the likelihood of access is certain. However, we can't tell you what the impacts might be. We don't know the computer, what's on it, or what access the computer might grant. If having access is unacceptable, then don't grant access.

We also can't tell you if this person is trustworthy or if they might do malicious things.

Comment: @Inastalling Anydesk on VM would not change all mentioned?

Comment: Of course it would. But then, Anydesk is not installed on the desktop but a VM...

Comment: Additionally,  The mention of a VPN not working is a bit odd,  SSL VPN does exist, and VPN strategies that allow for roaming up are possible.

Comment: @AnthonyT Anydesk inside VMWare,not a bad idea?

Comment: @RichardRublev Not saying if AnyDesk inside a VM is bad, but I would prefer a VPN solution

Comment: @AnthonyT VMWare or ..?

Comment: @RichardRublev  User would connect via their own machine through an open VPN tunnel.  This way I can limit their access at the network level. I just don't like the idea of someone on my personal/work desktop even if it is a VM.

Again Personal preference.